# IntelliJ organize Imports auto add doesn't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In eclipse, I would write my code and at the end of it all, I would do CTRL+SHIFT+O and all my imports would be added and re-organized, etc.

I have already seen all the other answers to do CTRL+ALT+O (I changed this back to eclipse keymap) and I have already done all the settings possible. IntelliJ will just not ADD any new imports, I have to manually go to the broken import and press ALT+ENTER and then mouse over to import class, for EACH NEW CLASS. Sometimes, this doesn't happen and intelliJ will actually work by itself.

Is there really no way to force an auto add imports??

This is how my Auto Import settings look like: [image: intelliJ auto-import settings]

Comment: What version of intellij are you using?  Also, shouldn't that last checkbox do this for you?

Comment: I'm using latest Android Studio. That's what I thought too, but sometimes I have to manually alt enter it.

Comment: Weird. If you checked "add unambiguous imports on the fly" then they should be added automatically.

Comment: Now that I think about it, could it be my computer is just too slow? I'm usually on my desktop which has fairly high specs, and I'm on my laptop now because I'm travelling. I feel like intelliJ runs a lot slower than eclipse either way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to reformat the code *AND* optimize the imports, you can try <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (Reformat code).

Using that function you get a dialog box: specify the directory of files you want formated, and check "Optimize imports".

Comment: I do this as well, same behavior, doesn't make a difference. In eclipse I always did Ctrl + shift + o, Ctrl + shift + f, Ctrl +s, so I don't have an issue with that.

Comment: Yes i have same issue. ctrl+alt+o not working for auto import. I also check shortcut key in setting it is correct.